# Which method is better to save data nsdictionary or plist?

Tags: objective-c, plist, nsdictionary

I want to save data locally but i do not know which method is better nsdictionary or plist?Can anyone tell which method is better and why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I think maybe what you meant to ask is which is better, plist or binary.  If you save an `NSDictionary` to file using `writeToFile:` it will be stored as a plist.  So in that sense there is zero difference between the two.

However, you also have the option of converting an `NSDictionary` instance into a serialized `NSData` representation, and then storing the serialized data as a binary file.

As for which is better and why, that depends upon what you want to do.  The API for converting an `NSDictionary` to/from a plist file is more convenient to use than the API for serializing and reconstructing to/from `NSData`.  However, storing an `NSDictionary` as a plist file only works if everything in the dictionary is a plist object (instances of `NSData`, `NSDate`, `NSNumber`, `NSString`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`) and if all of your keys are of type `NSString`.  Otherwise your `writeToFile:` call will fail with frustratingly little information being provided about why.

So if your data structure meets the requirements for being stored as a plist and you cannot foresee it ever being changed such that it would no longer meet the requirements then you may find it more convenient storing it as a plist.  Otherwise your only option is to do a  binary serialization and storage using `NSData`.  You may prefer this latter option if you want to have code that cannot be accidentally broken by someone sticking a non-plist-object in your data structure.

Comment: What the difference in terms of performance? Binary should be faster in theory.